# PDF is incomplete when printed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, popup, jspdf

I'm using JSPDF and addHTML for printing PDF on fly. Problem is that on normal page it works fine but when I want to print modal screen i.e. popup, it only prints the Modals visible portion of the screen and the other part after scrolling is blank in PDF. I tried using split screen but still is shows blank portion.

```
const el = document.getElementById('card');
let options = {
    pagesplit: true
};

var pdf = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'landscape',
    unit: 'in',
    format: [20, 18]
})

pdf.addHTML(el, 0, 0, options, () => {
    pdf.save('card.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Provide JsFiddle link to help you better.

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="printJS('docs/printjs.pdf')">
    Print PDF
 </button>